# Cycles: Light bounces differently on a material for each frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[GIF of my animated object](https://imgur.com/LWNnZ9F)

I don't understand why my light looks so bad.
I tried merging overlapping vertexes, it removed around 300 but the problem was not fixed.
Is this a problem with SSS, or with the interaction with the other clipping materials such as the mozzarella?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by checking the *Face Orientation* and correcting the normals directions